# How to fetch Notes related to specific Accounts in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning, soql, salesforce-communities

How can I fetch Notes data related to a specific Account using SOQL query in Salesforce?

I tried with the below SOQL query but it gives me empty rows.

> SELECT Id, Title, Body FROM Note WHERE ParentId = '<Account_id>'

I am attaching a screenshot for better understanding.
[image]

I want to query the Notes which are marked in red color in the above image.

*PS: Am new to Salesforce*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uh, bit tricky for first task :)

`Note` is old object primarily used in old Salesforce UI, maybe you have heard of "classic" or "aloha". You are using new Lightning UI and the object you're looking for is [`ContentNote`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentnote.htm).

Old: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_erd_documents.htm
New: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_erd_contentnote.htm

To make matters bit messier ContentNotes are built on top of the solution for uploading Files, they're a special type of file. And that one is split into 2 tables - the header that can be linked to from many areas in the system (`ContentDocument`), wasting space on disk only once... and actual payload which can be versioned (`ContentVersion`)

Anyway: this should work

```soql
SELECT ContentDocument.Title, ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.VersionData
FROM ContentDocumentLink
WHERE LinkedEntityId = '001...'
AND ContentDocument.FileType = 'SNOTE'
```

Another, simpler way would be to use a flatter, readonly view of all the "files" linked to the record (old school attachments, new files, stuff uploaded as Chatter posts, stuff cross-linked from SharePoint for example...). You'd have to experiment with [`CombinedAttachment`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_combinedattachment.htm)

```soql
SELECT Name, (SELECT Title FROM CombinedAttachments)
FROM Account
WHERE Id= '001...'
```

Comment: How can i call ContentDocumentLink from Batch class? I am getting  SerialBatchApexRangeChunkHandler Internal Salesforce.com Error in Apex Batch

Comment: What do you need to do? You could make the batch's main loop go over accounts, then for each list of accounts passed to execute() (default is 200) run my query. Not as a query in a loop (evil), just passing multiple IDs.

Comment: Check if this is acceptable form for start() `select id, name,
(select contentdocument.title, ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.VersionData from contentdocumentlink where ContentDocument.FileType = 'SNOTE')
from account
limit 10`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found a workaround for that. Just calling all the records into a List and doing required condition check instead of calling it from batch

example of SOQL: SELECT Id, LinkedEntityId, ContentDocumentId, ShareType, Visibility FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId IN :accIds, - accIds is a list of all Account ids